# Lucene to perform document similarity

Tags: lucene, indexing

I have made the code to find the similarity between two documents by finding their tf and then their cosine values . But when i was looking at the standard examples on lucene , every program had made use of an index . 
My process involves a comparision between one reference document and other documents from a folder .

Do u think i should use indexing  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout the [MoreLikeThis class.](http://cephas.net/blog/2008/03/30/how-morelikethis-works-in-lucene/)

Comment: thanks .. but i guess this also makes use of indexing .. is it necessary to include indexing ? what are the advantages ?